# Still seeing TO DO status from the default workflow even after assigning a custom workflow for my project

Tags: jira

I have created a custom workflow where tickets or issues are submitted then the order of workflow steps is:

1. review (ALL)
2. business justificatioN
3. in progress
4. verification (ALL)
5. deployment
6. testing
7. done
8. ON HOLD (ALL)
9. RETIRED (ALL)

I created the custom workflow by making a copy of the default workflow with TODO IN PROGRESS, and DONE Status however when you go to edit an issue in my custom workflow you still have the option to change the status to TO DO (from the default workflow) even though my custom workflow is clearly the one which is selected for the Scrum project.

What do I need to modify so that the TO DO STATUS from the default workflow isn't showing up at the top of my issues.

For example if an issue is created using the custom workflow the STATUS defaults to REVIEW as expected as it is the first step in the workflow. When trying to transition it to the business justification step while viewing the issue a STATUS of TO DO is visible.

How can I remove the option to change the status to TODO given it is not part of my custom workflow which is applied to the project and is instead part of the default workflow.

Can I remove the default workflow for the project? to achieve this (I am not sure how to completely remove the default workflow) so far I have only been able to assign my own.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if either:

- The TODO status is still used in your custom workflow.
- You're looking at an issue that does not use your workflow. This is possible if your "Workflow Scheme" is not configured correctly. A project has a "workflow scheme" that can contain multiple "workflows" for different "issue types". You can review these settings in your project's settings. The documentation is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/configuring-workflow-schemes-802592719.html).